# Add decimal delimiter on IDs

Tags: sql, database

[image: Screenshot of my Accounts table]]

I need to add (decimal - 2 places) on project ids (`prjID`).

So far here is my messy code

```
UPDATE AxProject
   SET prjID = SUBSTRING(prjDescription, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', prjDescription,1) -1)
 WHERE prjID LIKE '% %' AND prjKey = prjProject AND prjKey > 2 AND prjKey <= '208'
```

Comment: Can you provide the datatype for project id column

Comment: it's varchar(30), but i can't change it in stored procedures, i have a lot of fixes to do on staging table

Comment: There may not be any trailing blanks after a VARCHAR value, which means the SUBSTRING operation may fail, leaving you with problems.   A LENGTH function should ignore trailing blanks, I believe.  Are you trying to remove the last two digits (always `00` in the example data)?

Comment: yes exactly, substring giving me error that it needs 2 or more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE AxProject SET prjID = substring(prjID from 0 for char_length(prjID ) -1 ) || '.' || substring(prjID from '..$') ;
```